# What is the character expression for a new line in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a text box control on a page and I want people to add URLs, one on each line and then split those URLs into an array.

So, I'm trying to split them on the newline character. I've tried:

```
.split(Environment.Newline)
.split('vbcrlf')
.split(vbcrlf)
.split((char)Environment.Newline)
```

but all to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
.split(new []{Environment.Newline}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

This is because `Environment.Newline` is a string, so you must pass it in as an array of strings, as the function overload requires, also there needs to be a [`StringSplitOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions.aspx) value included. This can either be `StringSplitOption.None` or `StringSplitOption.RemoveEmptyEntries`.

Comment: Also had to add a string split option. Now looks like .Split(UrlSplit,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

Comment: Damn, I was too fast for my own good. You're quite right. I'll update my answer.

Comment: What's the difference between .RemoveEmptyEntries and .None?

Comment: Using RemoveEmptyEntries with the above .Split means that (say `Environment.NewLine` == `\n`) given the string "this is a string\n\nwith two new lines" you will get an array of 2 items ("this is a string" and "with two new lines"), but if you use None then you get an array of 3 items ("this is a string, "", and "with two new lines") because of the consecutive new line characters

Answer (score 2):

"\r\n" is the string representation

\r = carriage return
\n = line feed

Comment: Right, for windows. To keep things platform independent, you should be using `Environment.Newline`.